# Finding domain of $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$

Tags: calculus

Find the (maximum) domain of: $\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$

Well, I guess it is $2 - \sqrt2 \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ = $2- \sqrt{2(x^2 - 1)}$

from here, $x^2 - 1 \ge 0$ and then $ x \ge 1$ and $ x \ge -1$

What do you guys think?

Comment: It appears that you are "distributing" the big radical in your first step, is that right? If so that is not valid. Otherwise, here is a proof that $5=7$: $5=\sqrt{25}=\sqrt{16+9}=\sqrt{16}+\sqrt{9}=4+3=7$.

Comment: Also, if you reach $x^2-1\geq0$, then $x$ could be larger than $1$, but it could also be _smaller_ than $-1$. So your final implication needs one of its directions reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2-1 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x^2 \geq  1 \Rightarrow x \geq 1 \text{ or } x \leq -1$$

Also:

$$4-2 \sqrt{x^2-1} \geq 0 \Rightarrow 4 \geq 2 \sqrt{x^2-1} \Rightarrow 2 \geq \sqrt{x^2-1} \Rightarrow 4 \geq x^2-1 \Rightarrow 5 \geq x^2 \\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{-5} \leq x \leq \sqrt{5}$$

So:

$$1 \leq x \leq \sqrt{5}  \ \text{  or } -\sqrt{5} \leq x \leq -1$$

Therefore the domain is:

$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: -\sqrt{5} \leq x \leq -1 \text{ or } 1 \leq x \leq \sqrt{5} \}$$

Comment: You are welcome!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You are right on the first restriction, we need $|x|\ge 1$. We also need $4-2\sqrt{x^2-1}\ge 0$. This inequality is equivalent to $2\sqrt{x^2-1}\le 4$, or equivalently $x^2-1\le 4$, that is, $|x|\le \sqrt{5}$.

Thus a way of describing the (maximum) domain is that it is $\{x: 1\le |x|\le \sqrt{5}\}$.

Comment: My bad... Glad you posted.

Comment: You re welcome. The *style*  you are expected to use to describe the domain is course-dependent. For example, it could be $[-\sqrt{5},-1]\cup [1,\sqrt{5}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is wrong: $\sqrt{A-B}$ does not simplify to $\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}$ .

You have two places that can give trouble in calculation: the two square roots. Both expressions inside the square roots must be nonnegative. So your first inequality is $x^2-1 \ge 0$. Can you proceed from there?

Answer (score 1):

What can limit the domain of the expression is when you attempt to take the derivative of a strictly negative number.

The inner radical requires $$x^2-1\ge0,$$
i.e.
$$x\le-1\lor x\ge1.$$

And the outer radical requires
$$4-2\sqrt{x^2-1}\ge0,$$
or
$$2\sqrt{x^2-1}\le4,$$
 by squaring,
$$x^2-1\le4,$$
i.e.
$$-\sqrt5\le x\le\sqrt5.$$
In conclusion, by "anding" the conditions,
$$-\sqrt5\le x\le-1\lor1\le x\le\sqrt5.$$